# Retrieve Data from Firebase with random key

Tags: android, json, firebase

I'd like to retrieve the value of each key from my json file cardInfo

```
"cardInfo" : {
"-KF3fzOc3e68jRpCkLRb" : 6869098993309203,
"-KF3g0fQUJHcexwAFzxz" : 6764366404306628,
"-KF3hHOdj-siBxLMNgLa" : 4368998299921475,
"-KF3hLzxQsmTP9MJ6iVe" : 8779395075647930,
"-KF3hM3_mOn_VoN9-bW6" : 6867202628499185,}
```

But since i'm using Push method for saving these random numbers , which method shall i use to get access to those values through these random keys to save them into some TextViews.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `public Iterator<String> keys()`

> Returns an iterator of the String names in this object. The returned
>   iterator supports remove, which will remove the corresponding mapping
>   from this object. If this object is modified after the iterator is
>   returned, the iterator's behavior is undefined. The order of the keys
>   is undefined.

Example:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject json = jObj.getJSONObject("cardInfo");
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON-ERROR",e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel but some of these methods doesn't work with the Firebase SDK, i'll try with the same principles.

Comment: Maybe If you share some of your code I could help you